# Converting String arguments to Char in Scala

Tags: scala

Example code:

```
object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(args(0).toChar)
  }
}
```

I have two arguments. The first one is a single letter, whereas the second one is a sequence of letters.

How can I convert the first string argument to Char? I tried the `toChar` function, but without success (`error: value toChar is not a member of String`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args(0).toCharArray` converts a string to an array

if you are sure you want only the first char, try `args(0).head` or more safely: `args(0).headOption`

Comment: it would be a Array[Char] that way. the head function worked fine

Comment: Yes, i added other solutions also